# PyCharm/IntelliJ Python multi-line language injection rules

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

It's possible to force language injection onto a string literal via comments like:

```
# language=RegExp
fruit = "(apple|orange|banana)"
```

But that only works for the immediately following line, and I will have a long block of these. Is there any way to perform language injection over a region? Something like:

```
# language=RegExp begin
fruit = "(apple|orange|banana)"
vegetable = "(lettuce|onion|zucchini)"
...
# language=RegExp end
```

Comment: It is not possible, unfortunately. But feel free to submit a feature request in PyCharm's issue tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY